# Is there a way to pass in an array to rs.exe

Tags: command-line, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rs.exe

I am trying to make a command line util to let me register updates to my TFS SSRS reports.

I am using rs.exe.  It has the -v option where you can pass in a parameter.  Is there a way to pass in an array (or some kind of collection).

I would like to pass in an array of Data Source Names.

Comment: Have you looked at [RSScripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62)?

Comment: @Jay - yes.  It does not seem to have a way to switch Data Sources.  It only adds them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and came up with this solution:

**Powershell**

```
$RssScriptPath = "C:\myRssScript.rss"
$TargetSsrsServer = "http:\\localhost\reportserver"
$MyStringArray = "val1", "val2", "val3"

& rs.exe -i $RssScriptPath -s $TargetSsrsServer -v _myStringArray=$MyStringArray
```

**Rss script (VB)**

```
Dim _phrase As String() = _myStringArray.Split(",")
Dim _values As String() = _phrase(0).Split(" ")

   For index As Integer = 0 To _values .GetUpperBound(0)
    PublishReport(_values(index))
   Next
```

I only tried with a strings, but you may be able to use the same strategy to pass other types.